# Importing shapefile from website if download link is compressed file?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, compression

I'm trying to write an SQL query with PostgreSQL to download and import multiple shapefiles to tables in my database. All the links are of the form : `https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_STATE-FIPS-CODE_140_00_500k.zip`.

I've tried using `wget` however I'm having trouble since the file is compressed and I'm not sure how to decompress it with a query.

Comment: piüe it to `ogr2ogr`

Comment: You could download all the zips to a folder, unzip them to a different folder (both using python) and point the entire folder to a OGR/SHP foreign data wrapper and read them all that way. You could then use an insert to dump them into a postgres table.

Comment: You don't decompress it with a query. You decompress it independently, *then* query it.

Comment: Are you doing `wget` in an SQL query? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to make a conversion with one ogr2or command by reading data as /vsizip/vsicurl/[https://address_to_zip] as documented in https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html.

Test with the URL that is used in the document goes well

```
ogrinfo -ro -al -so /vsizip/vsicurl/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/autotest/ogr/data/poly.zip  --config gdal_http_unsafessl true
INFO: Open of `/vsizip/vsicurl/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/autotest/ogr/data/poly.zip'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: poly
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 10
Extent: (478315.531250, 4762880.500000) - (481645.312500, 4765610.500000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["OSGB 1936 / British National Grid",
    GEOGCS["OSGB 1936",
        DATUM["OSGB_1936",
            SPHEROID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7001"]],
            TOWGS84[446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6277"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4277"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-2],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996012717],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",400000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",-100000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","27700"]]
AREA: Real (12.3)
EAS_ID: Integer64 (11.0)
PRFEDEA: String (16.0)
```

However, I could not make it to work with url https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_36_620_l2_500k.zip. By looking at the debug info GDAL wants to know the file size but gets zero length as an answer

```
VSICURL: GetFileSize(https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_36_620_l2_500k.zip)=0  response_code=200
```

I could convert data directly from the zip into GeoPackage when I downloaded it first into a local file. The command that I used in the successful test was

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg to_remove.gpkg /vsizip/gz_2010_36_620_l2_500k.zip -nlt promote_to_multi
```

For making the conversion into PostGIS read https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html and modify the ogr2ogr command accordingly.

Comment: pretty sure the data URL needs a `/` at the end, but it still doesn't work with the given URL...

Comment: @ThingumaBob I added a test case that works.